Spring security 6.2 , SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() gives null
I have upgraded to springboot 3.2 from 2.**.
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() gives me null , even though BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter succesfully authenticated the request,
my security configuration is as below
@Bean
@Order(1)
SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
APIKeyAuthFilter filter = new APIKeyAuthFilter(API_KEY_HEADER_NAME);
filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
http
      .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> { 
       request.requestMatchers("/**").authenticated().anyRequest().hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_USER");
        })
        .securityContext(securityContext ->{  securityContext
                .requireExplicitSave(false)
                .securityContextRepository(new DelegatingSecurityContextRepository(
                        new RequestAttributeSecurityContextRepository(),
                        new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository()
                    ));
                
        })
        .oauth2ResourceServer(o -> {
                  o.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults());
                  o.bearerTokenResolver(this:: tokenExtractor);
        })
        .sessionManagement(sess ->{
            
        sess
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
                .requireExplicitAuthenticationStrategy(false);
})      
        .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
        .cors(cors -> cors.disable());
       
        return http.build();
        
        //  .oauth2ResourceServer(o -> o.bearerTokenResolver(this:: tokenExtractor))
}

when I try to fetch authentication , I get null
 final SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    if (!Objects.isNull(securityContext)) {
        final Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();
        System.out.println(":::::::::::: authentication :: "+authentication);

Can somebody point me out what I am doing wrong.
Any help would be highly appreciated.
